# Limit the number of acf content when displaying in post loop

Tags: custom-field, loop, post-meta, pagination

I display post images by this way  in the loop .

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('POST-IMAGES');
$size = 'medium'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $images ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image_id ): ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the problem is that some times post images could be more than I want to display. How can I limit image number. Example . I want to display maximum 4 images even post have more images than 4. please help me

Comment: This is a basic PHP question, and for example, `foreach ( array_slice( $images, 0, 4 ) as $image_id )` would do what you asked.

Comment: thanks you very much. it works like charm.